# Facebook PHP SDK - Post to user's wall as app and not user. How?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I have a few questions about Facebook PHP SDK I haven't found the answers to yet, hope someone here can help.

I have made a page where users connect to Facebook to be able to share things via my site on their wall. I don't want to use the offline_permission. But I need to be able to delay post, cause sometimes we need to confirm choices they use. I read that YOU CAN post at any time with stream_publish, but you need to post as THE APP and not THE USER. Right now I think I post as the user. How do I post as the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Facebook Authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), specifically the section titled "App Login" where it tells you how to authenticate as the application. Basically you navigate to this url: [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?%20%20%20%20client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials) and that will give you a session token to act as your page.

Comment: I just used: $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
It will get the user's token if avaiable, otherwise the app's.
Works like a charm.